# Help understand inequality algebra and stability analysis Du Fort-Frankel scheme PDE

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, stability-theory

the scheme is as follows

$ u_j^{n+1} = u_j^{n-1} + 2r ( u_{j+1}^{n} - u_j^{n+1} - u_j^{n-1} + u_{j-1}^{n})$

using the anstaz $ u_{j}^{n} = A \xi^{n} e^{i \omega j}$  and using the identity
$ e^{iw} +e^{-iw} = 2 cosw $

rearranging i get

$ (1+2r) \xi^{2} = -4r \xi cosw-(1-2r) = 0 $   where  r is r>0

for stability requires $ | \xi| \leq 1 $   and the roots distinct,

$ \xi \pm = \frac{1}{1+2r}( 2rcos\omega \pm \sqrt{4r^{2}cos^{2}\omega + 1-4r^{2}})$

simplify further using $ 4r^{2}cos^{2}w - 4r^{2} = -4r^{2}sin^{2}w$

$ \xi \pm = \frac{1}{1+2r}( 2rcos\omega \pm \sqrt{1-4r^{2}sin^{2}\omega })$

from this point I don't understand the solution in the book, if someone could explain it to me,

case 1 : $1-4r^{2}sin^{2}\omega$ <0 $ \xi _+ $ and $ \xi_ -$ are complex,

$| \xi _ -|^{2} = | \xi_+|^{2}$ =  $\frac{4r^{2}cos^{2}w + 4r^{2}sin^{2}\omega + 1}{(1+2r)^{2}} $
 = $ \frac{4r^{2} +1}{(1+2r)^{2}}$

$ 0 < \frac{4r^{2} +1}{(1+2r)^{2}} <1 $

therefore $| \xi _ -|\leq 1   $ and $| \xi_+| \leq 1 $

how have they concluded this and how do you get this inequality?

case 2: $1-4r^{2}sin^{2}\omega >0$

$\frac{1}{1+2r}( 2rcos\omega +\sqrt{4r^{2}cos^{2}\omega + 1-4r^{2}}) \leq \frac{2r cos\omega +1}{1+2r} \leq1$

therefore $\xi_+\leq1$ where we have used the fact that

$ 0< 1-4r^{2}sin^{2} \omega \leq 1$     how did they get  this inequality ?

how does one conclude that $\xi +$ is less than or equal to one from the above?

Comment: If you're asking about $$0<\frac{4r^{2}+1}{(1+2r)^{2}}<1$$ then just expand the denominator and use $r>0$. Also, $$0<1-4r^{2}\sin^{2}\omega\le1$$ as $4>0,r^{2}\ge0$ and $\sin^{2}\omega\ge0\implies4r^{2}\sin^{2}\omega\ge0$, hence $1-4r^{2}\sin^{2}\omega\le1$. Hence, $$\frac{1}{1+2r}\bigg[2r\cos\omega+\sqrt{1-4r^{2}\sin^{2}\omega}\bigg]\le\frac{1}{1+2r}\bigg[2r\cos\omega+\sqrt{1}\bigg]=\frac{1}{1+2r}\bigg[2r\cos\omega+1\bigg]$$ Then notice that $\cos\omega\le1$, hence $$\frac{1}{1+2r}\bigg[2r\cos\omega+1\bigg]\le\frac{1}{1+2r}\bigg[2r\cdot1+1\bigg]=1$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! I now understand the second part, however I am still not understanding the first case. I expanded the denominatior and just get $ \frac{4r^{2}+1}{1+4 +4r^{2}}$Which is all positive, but how wild I assume this is also less than 1?thank you

Comment: If $r > 0$, $$4r^{2} + 4r + 1 > 4r^{2} + 1$$ and hence $$1 > \frac{4r^{2} + 1}{4r^{2} + 4r + 1}$$ Alternatively, you can use $$\frac{4r^{2} + 1}{(1 + 2r)^{2}} = \frac{1 + 4r + 4r^{2} - 4r}{(1 + 2r)^{2}} = \frac{(1+2r)^{2} - 4r}{(1+2r)^{2}} = 1 - \frac{4r}{(1+2r)^{2}}$$ and as $4r/(1+2r)^{2} > 0 \dots$

Comment: Thank you! Fully understand now. I think if you post your comments as answer I can accept you have answered the question, cause I can’t do it with comments.

Comment: It's all good, I can't be bothered to type up the comments into a solution. Also, if you now understand the solution, I'm happy anyway.